# CORS with axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying send a get request to a valid server using axios an vue.js but I keep getting `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://37.152.185.50:8080/hotels/tblisi' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` I've tried setting the `Content-Type` header but no luck. I have the same issue with axios and vue.js in another project too which is apparently working fine for others.

```
vm = new Vue({
    el: '#main-container',
    data: {
        city: 'istanbul',
        hotels: []
    },
    methods: {
        setCity: function (city) {
            this.city = city;
            axios({
                method: 'get',
                data: {},
                url: 'http://37.152.185.50:8080/hotels/' + this.city,
                headers: {
                    'content-type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Also I don't have access to the server to change the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is type of response header and this must be set by the server.

So you need to change the server's CORS policy to allow your origin: http://localhost:63342 .

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that. Is there any workaround?

Comment: If it's just for development, you can use a tool to inject the headers into the response. Something like Requestly, which is a Chrome extension, or Charles, which is a proxy at the OS level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Proxy server to avoid CORS Error.
Write this codes at vue.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8080',
                changeOrigin: true,
                pathRewrite: {
                    '^/': ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```